# Error `Cross-device link` when set logrotate mode `create 0644 root root` in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logrotate, datadog

In order to rotate pod logs, [logrotate pod](https://github.com/blacklabelops/logrotate) is used in kubernetes. By default, logrotate will use `copytruncate` mode to create a new rotated file, however [`datadog`](https://www.datadoghq.com/) cannot work well in this mode, failed to retrieve pod log occasionally.

So I try to set the mode to `create 0644 root root`, but the following error comes up

`Cross-device link`

And `logrotate` failed to rotate logs either.

Could someone help me to resolve this issue or is there any better practice on rotate pod logs?

Comment: Might be best to reach out to support@datadoghq.com. I don't really see why the copytruncate turning would cause any problem.

Comment: @stephenlechner, I have contact with the datadog support, unfortunately, there is no progress...